# How do I convert missing values into strings?

Tags: f#, missing-data, deedle

I have a `Deedle` `DataFrame` of type `Frame<int,string>` that contains some missing values. I would like to convert the missing values into empty strings `""`. I tried to use the `valueOr` function but that did not help. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my `DataFrame`:

```
let s1 = Series.ofOptionalObservations [ 1 => Some("A"); 2 => None ]
let s2 = Series.ofOptionalObservations [ 1 => Some("B"); 2 => Some("C") ]
let df = Frame.ofColumns ["A", s1; "BC", s2]
```

Typing `df;;` in `FSI` yields some information including

`ColumnTypes = seq [System.String; System.String];`. So the values of `df` are of type `string` and not `string option`.

This is the function `valueOr`:

```
let valueOr (someDefault: 'a) (xo: 'a option) : 'a =
    match xo with
    | Some v -> v
    | None -> someDefault
```

I defined an auxiliary function `emptyFoo` as:

```
let emptyFoo = valueOr ""
```

The signature of `emptyFoo` is `string option -> string`. This means `emptyFoo` should not be acceptable to the compiler in the following command:

```
let df' = Frame.mapValues emptyFoo df
```

This is because the values of `df` are of type `string` and not `string option`.

Still, the compiler does not complain and the code runs. However, `df'` still has a missing value.

Is there a way to transform the missing value into the empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Deedle documentation for `Frame.mapValues`:

> Builds a new data frame whose values are the results of applying the specified function on these values, **but only for those columns which can be converted to the appropriate type for input to the mapping function**

So the mapping does nothing because strings are found, rather than string options.

I noticed another function that seems to do exactly what you want.

```
let df' = Frame.fillMissingWith "" df
```

The key thing I noticed was that Deedle shows those missing values as `<missing>`, suggesting that it uses it's own representation (as opposed to `option` for example). With that knowledge I guessed that the library would provide some way of manipulating missing values, so I explored the API by doing `Frame.` in my IDE and browsing the list of available functions and their documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I have used `fillMissingWith` for `float` values, some mental barrier stopped me from thinking about using it for strings.